# MySQL Transaction across several InnoDB databases on one server

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, innodb

I have some quick questions on MySQL InnoDB engine Transaction. I have some databases in this format (db_1, db_2, db_3 etc..)

I want to insert / update to any of the database within the transaction like as below,

```
BEGIN
USE DB_1;
//Insert / Update into DB_1 tables

USE DB_2;
//Insert / Update into DB_2 tables
COMMIT
```

Is it ok ? or do I need to put separate transaction for every database as below,

```
BEGIN
USE DB_1;
//Insert / Update into DB_1 tables
COMMIT

BEGIN
USE DB_2;
//Insert / Update into DB_2 tables
COMMIT
```

Are there any problems switching multiple database within a single transaction as in the first method. Is transaction database level or at global level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Obviously `DB_1` and `DB_2` are on the same server. If they are ever going to be on different servers, clustering is in your future! :-)

You might consider qualifying the names of your tables rather than employing `USE` statements. It's possible this will simplify your logic.

For example,

```
  BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO DB_1.mytable (myid, mycol) VALUES (1,'a');
  INSERT INTO DB_2.histable (hisid, hiscol) VALUES (1,'b');
  SELECT whatever
    FROM DB_1.mytable AS m
    JOIN DB_2.histable AS h ON m.myid = h.hisid;
  COMMIT;
```

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. As you said, here in my case all the databases are in the same server. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Prabu Did that work for you? Was that really transactional over 2 databases withing one RDBMS?